# Click on submit button behaviour

Tags: java, css, selenium-webdriver

Could someone please assist me in following:
I have button on several languages, which have to click on it. On EN it works correct, while on other languages when doing the same action, it behave as I am holding pressed left button on mouse and moving from left to right through button. It looks like as on screenshot below and HTML is also below.

[image]

HTML on DE page:

```
<div class="column large-12 text-center">
<input id="post-tip-submit" type="submit" class="button secondary expand" value="Veröffentlichen">
<div id="post-tip-loader-9" class="loader-large"><div>Loading...</div>   </div><br><br>
</div>
```

And on EN page:

```
<div class="column large-12 text-center">
<input id="post-tip-submit" type="submit" class="button secondary expand" value="Publish">
<div id="post-tip-loader-9" class="loader-large"><div>Loading...</div></div><br><br>
</div>
```

It looks same except 'title' of button, but somehow click on EN button open next page, while click on other language button remains stuck on that page and button disappear (on both languages) after that 'click'.

**One more thing:** on EN page that **submit** button is much wider than on rest of languages (not sure how is important last statement).

Tried following code without success:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#post-tip-submit")).isDisplayed();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#post-tip-submit")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
    Thread.sleep(7000);
```

Also, this one:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#post-tip-submit")).isDisplayed();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#post-tip-submit")).click();
    Thread.sleep(7000);
```

XPATH simply does not find that element, CSS does
Please, assist

Comment: Please post a link to the page. Both of the elements have the same ID and you have code that you tried using it but didn't indicate why it didn't work. Did you get an error or ? Whenever you post code, you should always indicate why it didn't work... error message or at least a description of what didn't go as expected

Comment: Also, you state that XPath doesn't work but a CSS selector does. My guess is that those two locators were not equivalent but you didn't post the XPath.

Answer (score 1):

an id is for an unique element. Try using a class, for example class="post-tip-submit" and cssSelector(".post-tip-submit"). Lets see if it works better?

Answer (score -1):

Css selector is based on your markup hope it helps.

```
    static Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
        .withTimeout(elementWaitTime, SECONDS)
        .pollingEvery(2,SECONDS)
        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);



WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input.button[type=submit]")));
element.click()
```